# How to group a object with styles using regular expressions?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string

```
" 'backgroundColor': someVaraible,
  'border': '1px solid red',
  'line-height': 1,
  'background-color': 'rgba(142, 27, 95, 1)' "
```

How to get an array of strings using Regexp ?

```
[
  "'backgroundColor': someVaraible",
  "'border': '1px solid red'",
  "'line-height': 1",
  "'background-color': 'rgba(142, 27, 95, 1)'"
 ]
```

Comment: string don't have line break!

Comment: The string you posted has line breaks.

Comment: Seems like you might want to use a real CSS parser.

Comment: @FelixKling I don't think that will work since it isn't valid CSS

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn: Could just add a dummy `div {....}` around the string. *edit:* Oh, but the quotes around the property names... yeah, I guess it's not possible then.

Comment: You would also have to convert the commas to semicolons.

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn: So many things I overlooked  :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use split with a regular expression that looks for commas that are not between parentheses (this is a negative lookahead).

```
/,(?![^(]+\))/
```

```js
let items = "'backgroundColor': someVaraible, 'border': '1px solid red', 'line-height': 1, 'background-color': 'rgba(142, 27, 95, 1)'"
  
console.log(
  // Split on commas not between parentheses
  items.split(/,(?![^(]+\))/)
    // Do some cleanup on the strings
    // trim() -> trim the trailing whitespace
    .map(i=>i.trim())
)
```

Comment: string don't have line break)

Comment: What you have has line breaks... are those actually not in the string?

Comment: I have updated it to act on the commas instead of line breaks.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest method would just use the String.split(). In your case just use "," as the delimiter.
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp

Comment: Splitting by comma will break up the rgba value.

Comment: True, I guess they could end each line with a semicolon instead and use that.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you just want to do some loose string matching and not support all CSS syntax. In your example, you could just split the string by line breaks:

```
var items = str.split(/\r?\n/);
```

Parsing all valid CSS syntax would be very complex. Within a browser, you can use the built-in CSS parser to extract the individual rules:

```
var doc = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument(''),
    style = document.createElement('style');
style.textContent = '.myClass {color: #000;}';
doc.body.appendChild(style);
console.log(style.sheet.cssRules);  // List of CSS rules
```